# What type of plain text arrays are there?

Tags: php, arrays, json, lua, deserialization

So I'm doing a mod for a program that seems to use lua, XML and JSON?
And it retrives and parses plain text arrays from a webrequests, like this:

a:2:{a:3:{s:2:"id";s:3:"123";s:4:"test";i:4:"1234";i:1:0;s:"test";}s:1:"a";s:1:"b";}

```
a:2:{
    a:3:{
        s:2:"id";s:3:"123";
        s:4:"test";i:4:"1234";
        i:1:0;s:"test";
    }
    s:1:"a";s:1:"b";
}
```

The syntax seems obvious, s = string, a= array, i = int, followed by the number of characters/entries. I looked on JSON objects and they seem identical but without the number of chars/entries.
I can't find the function where it parses that and I need to parse it, so my questions are:

1. Is this a known type of plain-text array? (On any language)
2. Does anyone know of a function on lua (or other identical language
   for that matter) to parse this?

Comment: This is a serialized data You need to unserialize and then decode the json data.

Comment: What does a number right after `a:` mean?

Comment: "a= array, i = int, followed by the number of characters/entries", so a:2, means it's an array with 2 entries

Comment: But there are 3 entries there (a nested array and two strings).  If all the items must be paired (as key-value), why the array `a:3:{...}` is not paired with a key?

Comment: I wrote that by hand, but I think that's how it works, the 2 strings are a key-value pair hence they are counted as only 1 entry

Comment: Looks very similar to PHP's serialize() output.

Comment: [Definition](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/classes_objects/serialization.html) of this format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is php serialize format
I would suggest to use `lua-phpserialize` library.

https://github.com/agladysh/lua-phpserialize

usage

```
local luatable={}
luatable[#luatable+1] = "asdasd"
luatable[#luatable+1] = 100
luatable[#luatable+1] = -123
local phpsrl = phpserialize.phpserialize(luatable,3);
```

Comment: That library can only serialize.  But OP wants to perform the reverse operation - `unserialize`.

Comment: I got a nice function to unserialize from here: https://gist.github.com/cristobal/3647759

Comment: @user572420 , approve if it was helpful